# Measuring Download Speed in curl and c++. Am I doing it correctly?

Tags: c++, curl

I am trying to figure out how to calculate current download speed while downloading Folder of many file(Its not a single file that I am downloading). And I am not able to do it correctly, and now going through it for many hours, its getting too confusing. The download speed sometimes go too high and sometimes its 0.

I am using curl and c++.

In my Download Function the program recursively download each file till all the files are being downloaded.

This is how I setup curl to call TraceProgress function during download:

```
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, TraceProgress );
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, &response );
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0 );
```

Here is the remaining code:

```
    double totalDownloadableSize = 0; // total size of the download, set prior to starting download of the first file
    double downloadedSizeTillNow = 0; // total size downloaded till now - keep adding file size that just completed downloading
    double currentDownloadingSize = 0; // size that we are downloading - downloadedSizeTillNow + bytes downloaded of the current file (in TraceProgress Function)
    double oldDownloadNow = 0; // size of the old download bytes of that particular file


    string fileDownloading = "";
    string tempFileDownloading = "";

    time_t startSeconds;
    time_t oldSeconds;

    int downloadIterationCounter = 0;




    int TraceProgress( void *clientp, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow )
    {

        // add size downloaded till now of this file to the total size downloaded till now
        currentDownloadingSize = downloadedSizeTillNow + dlnow;

        double rem = ( ( totalDownloadableSize - currentDownloadingSize ) / 1024 ) / 1024;

        // get current time in seconds
        time_t currentSeconds = time (NULL);

        // get elapsed time since last itiration
        time_t secondsElapsedSinceLastItiration = currentSeconds - oldSeconds;

        double downloadSinceLastIteration;
        if ( oldDownloadNow < dlnow )// so that we don't get wrong data when download file changes
        {
            downloadSinceLastIteration = dlnow - oldDownloadNow;
        }
        else
        {
            downloadSinceLastIteration = dlnow;
        }

        // calculate current download speed : (dlnow - oldNow) / (current time - oldTime)
        double currentDownloadSpeed = downloadSinceLastIteration / (double)secondsElapsedSinceLastItiration;


        // if downloading file name is not same as it was in the last call to this function
        // change the display text and save the name in the temp. This approach will avoid unnecessory
        // text change calls.
        if ( fileDownloading.compare( tempFileDownloading ) != 0 )
        {
             tempFileDownloading = fileDownloading;
             string dlfilename = "Downloading:  " + fileDownloading;
             SetWindowText( hDownloadingSTATIC, dlfilename.c_str() );// set text to static control
        }


        if ( downloadIterationCounter == 4 )
        {
             std::ostringstream strs_dn;
             strs_dn << (unsigned int)( rem );
             std::string downloadNow = strs_dn.str();


             string remSize = "Remaining:  " + downloadNow + " MB";
             SetWindowText( hRemainingDownloadSTATIC, remSize.c_str() );// set text to static control


             double idownloadSpeed = currentDownloadSpeed / 1024;

             std::ostringstream strs_dnSp;
             strs_dnSp << (unsigned int)( idownloadSpeed );
             std::string downloadSpeed = strs_dnSp.str();

             string downSize = "Download Speed:  " + downloadSpeed + " KB/s";
             SetWindowText( hDownloadSpeedSTATIC, downSize.c_str() );// set text to static control


             oldSeconds = currentSeconds;// save in old
             oldDownloadNow = dlnow;// save in old


             downloadIterationCounter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
             downloadIterationCounter++;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems like you're writing a GUI program - I think it's not the best idea to update the UI from anywhere but the main thread.

Comment: Maybe that's the reason I am experiencing weird graphics errors, like skin of the app going blank grey ? :o  What is the correct way would you suggest ? The download needs to be in its separate thread.

Comment: Why not ask `pthread_main()` to do that (only updating the UI)?

Comment: How can I do that, When the downloading is going on in a separate thread ? Downloading in the main thread will mean, no refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>`dlnow - oldDownloadNow` is probably wrong. You should be just using `dlnow` instead. You don't need `oldDownloadNow` at all, unless you want to show the download speed *rate of change*.</s>

> <sub>I was confused by the `dltotal` and `dlnow` names. `dltotal` is the *expected* total bytes downloaded, and `dlnow` is bytes downloaded so far. So one does need `oldDownloadNow`, and `dlnow - oldDownloadNow` is the current delta.</sub>

This fragment

```
    if ( oldDownloadNow < dlnow )
    {
        downloadSinceLastIteration = dlnow - oldDownloadNow;
    }
    else
    {
        downloadSinceLastIteration = dlnow;
    }
```

has an error: `oldDownloadNow == dlnow` means that nothing was downloaded since the last time. In this case the current momentary download speed is zero. The fragment should be replaced with

```
    downloadSinceLastIteration = dlnow - oldDownloadNow;
```

with no check whatsoever. If `libcurl` suddenly decidess that `oldDownloadNow > dlnow`, this will duly display negative download speed, which is the right thing to do. Never hide an error intentionally.

In addition, the `time()` resolution is too coarse. Use some kind of fine-grained timer.

Comment: That's a good point, if oldDownloadNow == dlnow then downloadSinceLastIteration = dlnow - oldDownloadNow; will mean downloadSinceLastIteration = 0; subsequently download speed will amount to 0. May be there should be a check to see if oldDownloadNow == dlnow and in that case do nothing ? And to go over the file change problem I am setting oldDownloadNow to 0 before the start of next file download, since there will be time when the last file just downloaded and the oldDownloadNow is set to much higher value and new file's dlnow is much lower, sounds good ?

Comment: Do nothing? Why? The current download speed is 0, report this like any other speed. In the file change situation your solution sounds right but you may want to test it.

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't see it that way.. hmmm... One last help if you please, can you help me with the problem @H2CO3 pointed above about updating UI from a non main thread ? Thanka a lot for your time.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Windows threading or GUI API, sorry.